# Specific class model binding in mvc 6

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, model-binding, custom-model-binder

I have a base view model with properties for `IsActive` and `LastUpdated`. Every time a users creates/edits an `entity` (inherited from the base view model) I would like it to run through my custom `model binder`.

How to achieve this in mvc 6.

Below is how I handled in previous version of mvc.

```
public class EntityViewModelBinder<T> : DefaultModelBinder
        where T : EntityViewModel
    {
        public override object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
        {
            var entity = base.BindModel(controllerContext, bindingContext) as EntityViewModel;

            if (entity != null)
            {
                entity.IsActive = true;
                entity.LastUpdated = DateTime.Now;

                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(controllerContext.HttpContext.Request["delete"]))
                {
                    entity.IsActive = controllerContext.HttpContext.Request["delete"].Contains("true") ? true : false;
                }
            }

            return entity;
        }
    }
```